# Efficient copy method in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, copy, hdfs, distcp

Is there a faster or more efficient way of copying files across HDFS other than `distcp`. I tried both the regular `hadoop fs -cp` as well as `distcp` and both seem to be giving the same transfer rate, around 50 MBPS.

I have 5TB of data split into smaller files of 500GB each which I have to copy to a new location on HDFS. Any thoughts?

Edit:
The original `distcp` is only spawning 1 mapper so I added `-m100` option to increase the mappers

```
hadoop distcp -D mapred.job.name="Gigafiles distcp" -pb -i -m100 "/user/abc/file1" "/xyz/aaa/file1"
```

But still it is spawning only 1 and not 100 mappers. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why not create an external table with target location and do `insert overwrite`.

Comment: Would that insert be faster than hadoop copy? We usually build external tables on parquet converted data but I can try this option.

Comment: Distcp is file level, **one mapper per file**. You cannot modify this. As @Ambrish said, inserts will be faster than distcp but you will not get the same file structure. The result will be numerous small files with each `file size ~= block size`. And from your distcp command with options `-pb`, I understand that `insert into table` is not an option you would be looking for.

Comment: @franklinsijo Thanks for the info about distcp. I didn't know it was one mapper per file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a pig script to read the data from path A, convert to parquet (which is the desired storage format anyway) and write it in path B. The process took close to 20 mins on average for 500GB files. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Can you pls share me how you did it with apache pig script? would it work for writing from hdfs to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this if you want to copy a subset of files from a folder to another in HDFS. It may not be as efficient as `distcp` but does the job and gives you more freedom in case you want to do other operations. It also checks if each file already exists there:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hdfs_path_1 = '/path/to/the/origin/'
hdfs_path_2 = '/path/to/the/destination/'
process = Popen(f'hdfs dfs -ls -h {hdfs_path_2}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
already_processed = [fn.split()[-1].split('/')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
print(f'Total number of ALREADY PROCESSED tar files = {len(already_processed)}')

df = pd.read_csv("list_of_files.csv")  # or any other lists that you have
to_do_tar_list = list(df.tar)
to_do_list = set(to_do_tar_list) - set(already_processed)
print(f'To go: {len(to_do_list)}')

def copyy(f):
    process = Popen(f'hdfs dfs -cp {hdfs_path_1}{f} {hdfs_path_2}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
    if std_out!= b'':
        print(std_out)

ps = []
for f in to_do_list:
    p = Process(target=copyy, args=(f,))
    p.start()
    ps.append(p)
for p in ps:
    p.join()
print('done')
```

Also if you want to have a list of all files in a directory use this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hdfs_path = '/path/to/the/designated/folder'
process = Popen(f'hdfs dfs -ls -h {hdfs_path}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
list_of_file_names = [fn.split(' ')[-1].split('/')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
list_of_file_names_with_full_address = [fn.split(' ')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
```